# UIAutomation Press a Link in a UIATextView

Tags: ios, ui-automation

According to the [documentation on UIATextView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIAElementClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/javascript/instm/UIAElement/links) I should be able to get a list of the links in a text view.

`links()` always returns and empty array. Is this a bug or is there another explanation why this could be happening.

- *I do have links in the text view.*
- *I am using a device, not the simulator.*

  ```
  UIATarget: name:iPhone Simulator rect:{{0, 0}, {375, 667}}
    UIAApplication: name:LinksAutomation rect:{{0, 20}, {375, 647}}
      UIAWindow: rect:{{0, 0}, {375, 667}}
        UIATextView: name:http://www.google.com value:http://www.google.com rect:{{0, 234}, {375, 200}}
  ```

Comment: Do you have `<a href="url">` links (as text), or actual [UIALink](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIALinkClassReference/) elements inside the UIATextView?  Can you post your element tree?

Comment: I have tappable links inside an NSAttributedString.

Comment: I filed a radar but Apple closed it saying that UIAutomation is no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that UIAutomation thinks your links are actually UIATextField elements, so you need to use the [textFields() method](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIAElementClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/javascript/instm/UIAElement/textFields) on the parent  element in order to retrieve them.

Alternatively, you can always look through the `.elements()` array, which will contain all the child elements regardless of type.

Comment: Sorry I was looking at the wrong element. I have the same problem on a simplified project with just a UITestView in it. I updated with question again with the element tree.

Comment: It's not appearing as a link, it's appearing as text -- `UIATextView` -- which happens to contain a link (that is probably rendered in some URL-specific way in your application).  Typically you'd only find `UIALink` elements inside a `UIAWebView`, so this is probably not a bug.